# Getting empty list on post reactions. What could be the reason?

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to read reactions on a post using the following graph-api call:

```
FB.options({version: 'v2.12'});
FB.setAccessToken('EAACEdE7w4Fp85PlhH0NYpZBddHyqkx6XXXX')


FB.api('/765898450131958_1518951084826687/insights?metric=page_actions_post_reactions_wow_total', (res) => {
    console.log(res)
});
```

But I always receive an empty data list. What could be the reason for this? For reference I am using [FB module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fb) to connect to graph-api.

The acces token I am using is my page-access token

Comment: Got `read_insights` permission from the user who created the page token?

Comment: @CBroe I am trying to read reactions from a page `(coca cola page)`. So we need to get permission to read reactions to the posts? We are already getting likes. How are reactions different?

Comment: No, you are trying to read **insights** data _about_ reactions here ... And since Feb. 5, 2018, you need to use a page access token with read_insights permission for _all_ page insights. So an admin from the Coca-Cola page would have to login to your app and grant it permissions first ... _“We are already getting likes”_ - just likes, or _insights_ about likes? Different thing. Outside of insights, reactions are available on a per-post-basis as well - but you will still need to use a page token for the page in question to get them.

Comment: @CBroe Okay, so are you saying that to get a reaction to post which includes (angry, wow. like, laugh etc..) Coca Cola admin will have to login to our app?

Comment: Yes that is what he is saying

Comment: You can get the overall count of each reaction on a per-posts basis, using field expansion and aliasing (post-id?fields=reactions.type(WOW).summary(1).as(wow),reactions.type(LIKE).summary(1).as(like), or .../feed?fields=...), but for everything else (insights, historical data, individual user profiles that gave the reactions) you will need a page token for the page in question.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the facebook app instance wasn't set to live. Once the facebook app instance is live, data array returns user info list with id and name . You can check that out in App Review Settings

Click your app instance -> Go To "App Review" -> Click "My Permissions & Requests".

You will see that there are two approved items. I think these are added or granted by default. But if your app is not live, the two permissions will not be active. That includes basic user information like name and profile picture.

TL;DR - Check if your app is live and also make sure that you are using Page Access Token rather than User Access Token.

Answer (score 2):

From official Facebook API documentation:

> On February 5th, 2018, User information will not be included in responses unless you make the request with a Page access token. This only applies to Comments on Pages and Posts on Pages.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.12/object/reactions